# Basic Linux Iptables firewall problem

Tags: linux, iptables

After inputting these commands into a terminal on a host with Iptables installed, no web pages are loaded after connecting to a wireless network with internet access.

I know it's something simple but I don't know what.

```
sudo iptables --policy INPUT DROP
sudo iptables --policy OUTPUT DROP
sudo iptables --policy FORWARD DROP

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --destination-port 53

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --destination-port 80

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p tcp --destination-port 443

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -p udp --destination-port 53


sudo /sbin/iptables-save
```

**Listed configuration after previous commands:**

```
user@debian:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain


user@debian:~$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 1095 packets, 131K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 33 packets, 2574 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
    8   480 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
 1072 70910 ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
```

In this case I'm just looking for basic DNS, HTTP and HTTPS. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo iptables --policy INPUT DROP
```

This by default drops every incoming traffic. You have no rule which makes exceptions to this policy, i.e. you only have OUTPUT rules which allow outgoing traffic. Typically one would have at least a rule to allow input matching connections which were established from inside, like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```